# How to Generate the Following Image Effect (Modulation)?

Tags: image-processing, matlab, fourier-transform

I was given the original image and I need to produce Image **1**. Does anybody know how I would go about this? I am on `MATLAB`, but I am more interested in the theory behind this.

**Original Image**

[image]

**Processed Image **

[image]

**NOTE** How would you achieve this through convolution of the `fft`s of the image and a sine wave along the vertical axis?

Comment: Your image is already on the Internet. Too late

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The image seems to be modulated, namely multiplied by Harmonic Signal along its columns.

This is the MATLAB Code:

```
mInputImage = im2double(imread('2vE0G.png'));
numRows = size(mInputImage, 1);
numCols = size(mInputImage, 2);

signalFreq = floor(numRows / 1.25);

vModulationSignal = 1 + (0.5 * cos(2 * pi * (signalFreq / numRows) * [0:(numRows - 1)].'));

mOutputImage = bsxfun(@times, mInputImage, vModulationSignal);

figure();
imshow(mOutputImage);
```

This is the result:

[image]

You can play with the parameters.

Enjoy...

Comment: What value was modulated? was it the magnitude?

Comment: The values of the pixels. I will try to create a MATLAB Example.

Comment: Should I be expecting this example soon?

Comment: I added MATLAB Code + Result. Enjoy...

Comment: would this also be possible by let's say  by creating the 2D Discrete Space Time Fourier Transformation of the sin wave along just the vertical axis and then multiplying this with the 2D Discrete Space Time Fourier Transformation of the Image itself and using Inverse fft, getting back the resultant image?

Comment: Sounds like a long-winded way to go about it @SharanDuggirala. The method Drazick shows above is the cleanest.

Comment: @SharanDuggirala, This is a modulation in Time Space, hence it is Convolution in Fourier Space. You can do that, but the above method would be easier and faster to implement.

Comment: @Drazick I am far more interested in that convolution as this would be theory that extends beyond MATLAB. If so, could you give me the specifics of it?

Comment: @SharanDuggirala, I don't undertsantd what you mean be "this would be theory that extends beyond MATLAB". MATLAB is just a language to implement the modulation. It can be done in any language you're using. This method is far more simple than doing it in the Fourier Domain. Don't go there. Anyhow, I think you should mark this as answered. Thank You.

Comment: By the way, if the usage of `bsxfun` troubles you I will edit something to show it in for regular way (Loop).

Comment: vModulationSignal = 1 + (0.5 * cos(2 * pi * (signalFreq / numRows) * [0:(numRows - 1)].')); Could you explain this to me?

Comment: It is the Harmonic Signal modulating the image. I'm adding `1` to make it oscillate between 0 and 1 instead of -0.5 and 0.5. Apply the function `plot` on it and you'll see.